# How to split string correctly according to its location in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am given a vector of strings as below:

```
t1 <- "                                                                                                                Total"     
t2 <- "                                          Total                                                              Stock Price"  
t3 <- "                                         Dividend                              Misc Gain      MTCC Gain         Gain"      
t4 <- "                         Proportion        Gain                                Position        Position       Position"    
t5 <- "   Year   Dividend Gain    Earned        (1) x (2)   Dividend Gain Misc Gain    (4) - (5)       (3) - (4)     (6) + (7)"   
t6 <- "  –––––        –––––        –––––          –––––         –––––       –––––        –––––          –––––          –––––"     
t  <- c(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
```

You can see from the above that it is the header of a table center-aligned to the last element **t6**.

Now I am trying to get the start and end index of the longest word in each column describe above.

For example, column 3 is

```
 Proportion 
   Earned   
    –––––
```

The longest word is `Proportion`, then I will try to find the start and end index of `Proportion` in **t4**.

Another example would be, for column 2

```
Dividend Gain
     –––––
```

The longest word(s) is `Dividend Gain`, the I will try to find the start and end index of `Dividend Gain` in **t5**.

How can I find the index I need from **t**?

Comment: What's hard about this isn't finding the longest words, it's the data structure you have. It's pretty tedious to figure out which column the words belong to. Can you set up ranges of characters to split up each t# into? Could you call the first 10 characters of each t# column 1 ect.?

Comment: @svenhalvorson The best would be he'd gave a `dput`.

Comment: If we think of each character position as a "column", it looks like there is at least 1 full char-column of spaces between each data-column. So I would start by getting the char positions of spaces for each row, and then looking at the intersection of those to find the breaks between data columns. You could then use something like `read.fwf` to parse the thing into data  columns. Trim whitespace, and then finding the longest word per column is pretty trivial. (Though the ragged  right edge might mess up a fixed width file parser, might need to just use `strsplit` or `substr` instead.)

Comment: @jay.sf It's copy/pasteable in valid syntax, doesn't seem like `dput` is necessary here.

Comment: @Gregor You were right, was quite sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to match the character positions of all vectors.

First, it may be helpful if all strings have the same number of characters. We can achieve this by adding some white space at the end.

```
# list string vector --
tl <- as.list(tx)

# make equal length --
tl <- lapply(tl, function(x) {
  d <- max(sapply(tl, nchar)) - nchar(x)
  if (d > 0) paste(x, Reduce(paste0, rep(" ", d - 1)))
  else x
})

# check equal num. of chars.
sd(sapply(tl, nchar))  
# [1] 0  # ok
```

Then we write a split function that cuts a vector at it's sequence jumps.

```
splitAtCuts <- function(x) 
  split(x, cut(x, x[which(c(2, diff(x[- length(x)]), length(x)) > 1)],
               include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE))
```

Now we can match the character positions in two steps.

```
# get character position matches --
# step 1
sl <- lapply(tl, function(x) {
  w <- which(strsplit(x, "")[[1]] != " ")
  return(splitAtCuts(w))
})
# step 2
pos <- sort(Reduce(union, unlist(sl)))
```

Now that we know where the characters are, we can derive the column positions,

```
# extract column positions --
cols <- splitAtCuts(pos)
```

that help us cut the string list into the desired matrix.

```
# cut into a matrix --
FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) 
  substring(tl[[x]], min(cols[[y]]), max(cols[[y]])))

M <- outer(seq(length(tl)), seq(length(cols)), FUN)
```

Finally we apply some cleaning.

```
M <- apply(M, 2, function(x) gsub("^\\s|\\s{2,}|\\s$", "", x))
M
```

***Yielding***

```
     [,1]    [,2]            [,3]         [,4]        [,5]            [,6]       
[1,] ""      ""              ""           ""          ""              ""         
[2,] ""      ""              ""           "Total"     ""              ""         
[3,] ""      ""              ""           "Dividend"  ""              ""         
[4,] ""      ""              "Proportion" "Gain"      ""              ""         
[5,] "Year"  "Dividend Gain" "Earned"     "(1) x (2)" "Dividend Gain" "Misc Gain"
[6,] "–––––" "–––––"         "–––––"      "–––––"     "–––––"         "–––––"    
     [,7]        [,8]        [,9]         
[1,] ""          ""          "Total"      
[2,] ""          ""          "Stock Price"
[3,] "Misc Gain" "MTCC Gain" "Gain"       
[4,] "Position"  "Position"  "Position"   
[5,] "(4) - (5)" "(3) - (4)" "(6) + (7)"  
[6,] "–––––"     "–––––"     "–––––"
```

---

***Data***

```
tx <- c("                                                                                                                Total", 
"                                          Total                                                              Stock Price", 
"                                         Dividend                              Misc Gain      MTCC Gain         Gain", 
"                         Proportion        Gain                                Position        Position       Position", 
"   Year   Dividend Gain    Earned        (1) x (2)   Dividend Gain Misc Gain    (4) - (5)       (3) - (4)     (6) + (7)", 
"  –––––        –––––        –––––          –––––         –––––       –––––        –––––          –––––          –––––"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for!